# MonoGame 3.4 + Android + SoundEffect = No Sound

Tags: android, audio, monogame

I have created simple MonoGame 3.4 android project to test audio playing.
I use SoundEffect to play sounds.
I tried XNB and WAV files. Nothing works... No sound.

Can someone explain me how to play sounds on android?

[My test project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B594D08BCAA8DF92!11762&authkey=!AO2DUMfbdX_6rec&ithint=file%2Czip)

Comment: Yesterday, I got updated versions of xamarin and monogame.
And problems with sounds are gone.

Answer (score 0):

are you using soun deffect instances?
to play sound effects, I recommend using these.
for example:

```
SoundEffect sound;
SoundEffectInstance instance;
sound = Content.Load <SoundEffect>("yourSound");
instance = sound.CreateInstance();
instance.Play();
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I use SoundEffectInstance. No sound

Comment: is it possible something's wrong with your sound? do songs play?